# Hold mouse at the edge of the screen to jump to other monitor on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, mac, display, mouse

I just set up my new TV on the wall above my iMac, so I arranged the external monitor above the main one in the preferences. The problem is that it got very hard to access my menu bar on top of my main monitor, when I move my mouse up so fast it would jump to the other screen! So I have to be precise and move my mouse slowly every time I want to hit something on my menu bar.

The question is, is there a way that I would have to hold my mouse on the edge of the screen to jump to the other monitor instead of it jumping right away?

Comment: I have a small app (that I made myself) that prevents the mouse from leaving the primary display, however, it doesn't really work too well (and I don't care because it served its purpose when I used it), but there's a reason why these utilities are sparse: "wxWidgets manual states that OSX guidelines forbid the programs to set the mouse pointer to a certain position programmatically. That might contribute to the reason there is not much support for such stuff in wx, especially since wx tries really hard to be compatible to everything possible."

Comment: @Husam If you're happy with my answer, please accept it. If you're not, please add a comment or edit your post with greater specificity to try to elicit another answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not by default in OS X there isn't a way to do that, and I don't know of any third-party utilities that do that either.

You could put the TV on an upper corner of the monitor (see below for ASCII art). Then you'd only be using a corner to transit the screens, not the whole top of the monitor.

```
               +--------------+
               |              |
               |              |
               |              |
+--------------+--------------+
|              |
|              |
|              |
+--------------+
```

Comment: hmmm. Nice idea!. I think I'm gonna use it temporarily until I find an app or something to fix this issue.
I hope there is a third party app to fix that problem!

Comment: You're welcome. I originally found this setup when trying to help a roommate fix an edge-scrolling bug in a game he was trying to use two monitors with, and it's been occasionally useful ever since.

Comment: @Husam Have you ever found an app for this? Having the same issue.